# How to set glDrawElements (x,y,z) to be relative to view port. Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am new to OpenGL, I just want to know How to set glDrawElements (x,y,z) to be relative to view port in Android?

I been fallowing this [example](http://blog.jayway.com/2010/12/30/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-%E2%80%93-part-vi-textures/) to draw my shape with glDrawElements.
it looks like this:

```
float textureCoordinates[] = {
                0.0f, 1.0f, //
                1.0f, 1.0f, //
                0.0f, 0.0f, //
                1.0f, 0.0f, //
        };

        short[] indices = new short[]{0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2};

        float[] vertices = new float[]{
                -1f, -1f, 0.0f,
                1f, -1f, 0.0f,
                -1f, 1f, 0.0f,
                1f, 1f, 0.0f};
```

and the draw looks like this:

```
// Counter-clockwise winding.
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
        // Enable face culling.
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        // What faces to remove with the face culling.
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
        // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during
        // rendering.
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
        // coordinates to use when rendering.
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVerticesBuffer);
        // Set flat color
        gl.glColor4f(mRGBA[0], mRGBA[1], mRGBA[2], mRGBA[3]);
        // Smooth color
        if (mColorBuffer != null) {
            // Enable the color array buffer to be used during rendering.
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
            gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mColorBuffer);
        }

        // New part...
        if (mShouldLoadTexture) {
            loadGLTexture(gl);
            mShouldLoadTexture = false;
        }
        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null) {
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            // Enable the texture state
            gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

            // Point to our buffers
            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);
            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);
        }
        // ... end new part.

        gl.glTranslatef(x, y, z);
        gl.glRotatef(rx, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(ry, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(rz, 0, 0, 1);

        // Point out the where the color buffer is.
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, mNumOfIndices,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndicesBuffer);
        // Disable the vertices buffer.
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        // New part...
        if (mTextureId != -1 && mTextureBuffer != null) {
            gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        }
        // ... end new part.

        // Disable face culling.
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
```

in my case x = y = z = 0

this is what I did on surface changed:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // Sets the current view port to the new size.
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        // Select the projection matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        // Reset the projection matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        // Calculate the aspect ratio of the window
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45, (float) width / (float) height, -1f, 1f);
        // Select the modelview matrix
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        // Reset the modelview matrix
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

This draw my texture in the midle of the screen( just like in the example) but how can I control it with my view port, and set the x,y,z relative to my view port?

**Edit:** Simply all what I want to do, is to set my screen size, and to draw a 2D image in the given coordination(x,y,z).

Comment: Can you give an example of what 'relative to the view port' means to you? Also, please say if you require perspective projection, or if  orthographic projection is acceptable.

Comment: @Tim check out my edit, hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just drawing a texture, I'd advise dropping the perspective projection and just doing a simple orthographic matrix.

Replace gluPerspective with something like

`glOrtho(0, screen_width, 0, screen_height, -1, 1);`

Then you can draw vertices at pixel locations, i.e. for a full screen texture:

```
float w = screen_width;
float h = screen_height;
float[] vertices = new float[]{
                0, 0,
                w, 0,
                0, h,
                w, h,
}
```

Comment: I am still missing some thing, can you please show me the onSurfaceChanged() and onDrawFrame() methods?